# Internet Explorer 'null or not an object' error - code works ok in Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript

Error: 'document.forms.0.Docunid_5.value is null or not an object

From function in JS Header in Lotus Notes form:

```
function saveWebViewDSFF(docnumber)
{
var docID = eval("document.forms[0].Docunid_" + docnumber + ".value");
var Comment9 = eval("document.forms[0].Comment9_" + docnumber + ".value");
var agentPath = "//www.mananua.com/foliw/ekupulibrary.nsf/(SaveWebViewDSFF)?openagent&unid=" + docID + "& Comment9=" + Comment9;
document.getElementById("agentOutput").src = agentPath;
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see the placement of this function in your HTML and where you call this function.

Comment: `eval` isn't necessary; just use `document.forms[0]["Docunid_" + docnumber].value;` instead, not that it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling this function?  If you are calling it before the form has a chance to load then move the call to the bottom of the HTML or use the window.onload function.

Example

```
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () { saveWebViewDSFF(5); };
</script>
</html>
```